# DSolve with conditions in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

I would like to solve this equation in Mathematica :

```
DSolve[{p'[r] == 1/((r^2)*(((R - S)/(R^3)) - (1/(r^2)*(1 - S/r)))^(1/2))}, p[r], r]
```

but I have some supplementary conditions:

- `S` is a strictly positive real
- `R > 3*sqrt(3)*S/2`
- I want the solution over the interval `r in ]R, +infinity]`

I am a beginner with Mathematica so how to specify these conditions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code appears to produce a solution (albeit large) on Mathematica 8

```
sol = DSolve[{p'[r] == 
1/((r^2)*(((R - S)/(R^3)) - (1/(r^2)*(1 - S/r)))^(1/2))}, p[r], r]
```

You can add the additional constraints on the solution, as part of the simplification. It doesn't appear to make a significant difference. Were you expecting something different?

```
Simplify[sol, {S, R} \[Element] Reals && S > 0 && R > 3*sqrt (3)*S/2]
```

**Minor Correction**

```
FullSimplify[sol, {S, R} \[Element] Reals && S > 0 && R > 3*sqrt (3)*S/2]
```

Appears to simplify some of the terms, but only a little.